# Prefill Stripe Shipping Address fields?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, stripes

I am trying to prefill the shipping address section but I can't, I have passed multiple different parameters specifying the shipping address but each one throws an error saying unknown parameter, help!

Now I am adding these line because I am getting error while posting this question saying that it looks like your post is mostly code add some lines.

This is the related code

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['billing_details'])) {
  $billing_details = $_SESSION['billing_details'];
  $name = $billing_details['name'];
  $email = $billing_details['email'];
  $number = $billing_details['number'];
  $city = $billing_details['city'];
  $country = $billing_details['country'];
  $addressl1 = $billing_details['addressl1'];
  $addressl2 = $billing_details['addressl2'];
  $postalcode = $billing_details['postalcode'];
  $state = $billing_details['state'];
}
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
$user_email = $_SESSION['email'];
$stripe_secret_key = "";

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe_secret_key);

// Fetch cart items from the database
$query = $query = "SELECT cart.qty, products.product_price, products.product_title 
FROM cart 
INNER JOIN products ON cart.p_id = products.product_id 
WHERE cart.user_email = '$user_email'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$line_items = [];

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $line_item = [
    "quantity" => $row['qty'],
    "price_data" => [
      "currency" => "inr", // Assuming your prices are in USD, change if necessary
      "unit_amount" => $row['product_price'] * 100, // Convert to cents
      "product_data" => [
        "name" => $row['product_title']
      ]
    ]
  ];

  $line_items[] = $line_item;
}

$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
  "mode" => "payment",
  "locale" => "auto",
  "customer_email" => $email,
  "line_items" => $line_items,
  "billing_address_collection" => "required",
  "shipping_address_collection" => [
    "allowed_countries" => ["IN"],
  ],
  "metadata" => [
    "name" => $name,
    "email" => $user_email,
    "phone" => $number,
  ]
]);


http_response_code(303);
header("Location: " . $checkout_session->url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it if `billing_address_collection` or `shipping_address_collection` are enabled, as your Checkout Session will add fields for the customer to add their address, and you can't prefill them.

If you already know your Customer's address, then [create a Customer](https://docs.stripe.com/api/customers/create) with their `address` and `shipping` information first, then create your Checkout Session with `customer => $customer->id`.
Your Session will still show the Billing country field, as that's required for the payment method (card), but it won't prompt the customer to enter their address.

Comment: I know the customer address, so I can prefill it by passing it in the customer parameter right? because I didn't understand your answer, can you give code example.

Comment: You can't do it.

Comment: The only thing you can do is create your customer ahead of time with address fields, then not collect the address on Checkout. You can't prefill the fields in Checkout

Comment: woah, you are fast! thanks btw!